# 1 GB Ram - Force Windows to use it

Tags: windows-7, memory, crash

I am wondering how to make Windows use all the ram. I have 4GB total ram, 3.67 GB available, but when I reach 1GB free in task manager, it complains about low memory. There is sometimes more than 1GB left over in free, and 400M in cached. Is there any way to disable Windows' low memory warning, and stop it from closing programs?

Comment: What is the error message? Low memory messages usually refer to Virtual Memory rather than Physical Memory and are caused by the pagefile being too small.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Win7 and Win8 using 5.7 GB of total 6 GB of RAM with no warnings. The message you see is probably about pagefile.

When your OS is running out of memory, it will start to move some programs from RAM to a disk space called *pagefile*. Pagefile is located on the hard drive, so it's waaay slower than RAM (about 250 times slower) but it's still better than just crashing some programs or entire system.

To increase your pagefile size:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `systempropertiesadvanced`, click OK.
- Click the *Settings* button in the *Performance* box.
- On the *Advanced* tab click *Change*.
- Select *Custom size* and type pagefile size in MBs (2048-3072 should be fine for you in my opinion).
- Click OK in all windows.